# How do I specify the EndpointAddress of a remote WcfService for a Silverlight application with multiple environments?

Tags: c#, silverlight, generics, wcf-binding

Alright, I have to deploy an ASP.NET application with a Silverlight component to multiple staging environments. The app depends on a Wcf service that is part of a different project but should always be hosted on the same server as my project (albeit on a different port). I do not want to have to remember to modify the address of the service's endpoint in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file every time I deploy to a new environment. Since there is no way to specify multiple ServiceReferences.ClientConfig(s) for a project (like you can with Web.Config(s)), I followed the advice [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/05/managing-service-references-in-silverlight-applications-for-different-environments.aspx) to create a reference for each environment in my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig. I then specify the name of the desired endpoint as a setting in the Web.config of my main project and pass it as an initial parameter to the Silverlight component. This is where I hit a wall. I use slsvcutil to generate an asynchronous client for my web service. As far as I can see, the only way to pass the desired endpoint address to my service client is through its constructor. Here is an example of the typical service call:

```cs
yield return new WebServiceResult<ServiceClient, MethodCallCompletedEventArgs>
(
  client => client.MethodNameAsync(param1, param2, ...),
  result => { .... }
);
```

Here is an abbreviated definition of the class WebServiceResult.

```cs
public class WebServiceResult<T, K> : IResult
  where T : new()
  where K : EventArgs
{
   private readonly Action<K> _callback;
   private readonly Expression<Action<T>> _serviceCall;
   private ActionExecutionContext _currentContext;

   public WebServiceResult(Expression<Action<T>> serviceCall, Action<K> callback)
   {
      _serviceCall = serviceCall;
      _callback = callback;
   }

   public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
   {
       _currentContext = context;
       var lambda = (LambdaExpression)_serviceCall;
       var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression)lambda.Body;
       var eventName = methodCall.Method.Name.Replace("Async", "Completed");
       var eventInfo = typeof(T).GetEvent(eventName);
       var service = new T();
       eventInfo.AddEventHandler(service, new EventHandler<K>(OnEvent));
       _serviceCall.Compile()(service);
   }

   public void OnEvent(object sender, K args)
   {
       if (_callback != null) _callback(args);
   } 
}
```

Since the generic T is constrained to be something with a parameterless constructor, how should I specify the name of the desired endpointAddress?